# Using rand() to shuffle cards but no shuffling happens

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, shuffle

I'm attempting to shuffle a deck of cards using the rand() function but for some reason when I try to see what the shuffled deck looks like, it comes out completely unshuffled. I'm not sure what I'm missing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void Deck::Shuffle()
{


for (int j = 0; j <= 51; j++)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int i = 1 + rand()%52;
    int k = 1 + rand()%52;

    Card temp = theDeck[i];
    theDeck[i] = theDeck[k];
    theDeck[k]= temp;
}
}
```

Edit: Thank you for your help everyone. I've fixed the code to now read.

```
 void Deck::Shuffle()
{
srand(time(0));

for (int j = 0; j <= 51; j++)
{

    int i = 1 + rand()%52;
    int k = 1 + rand()%52;

    Card temp = theDeck[i];
    theDeck[i] = theDeck[k];
    theDeck[k]= temp;
}
}
```

Comment: Even if I only seed once it doesn't fix the problem but thank you for the pointer.

Comment: @cadavid4j: How are you seeding once? Update your code.

Comment: Now look up [`std::random_shuffle`](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/random-shuffle.html).

Comment: Nvm...I see what you're saying. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: @FredLarson Thank you for the material to read up on as well. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Why the `1+` before `rand()%52`? That will generate numbers between 1 and 52, which means you never swap the first card, and you will occasionally access the array out of bounds. An array of size 52 has valid indexes from 0 to 51. There is no index 52.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`srand` should only be called once per program execution, not every time you call `rand`.  Your loop is running so fast, due to the speed of computers nowadays, that you are probably getting the same random number every single time, because you keep resetting the random number generator using the same seed (the time, which probably doesn't change at all through your execution). Fix that.

Update:
Your fix is better, but even better would be this:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    // the rest of your program here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from your random seeding problem, you use the expression `1 + rand()%52;` to calculate your swap indices. That generates a number between `1` and `52`, which means you're never shuffling the first card in the deck, and you're risking undefined behaviour by modifying data beyond the array bounds.

Comment: I was wondering why the first card never was shuffled. So basically I should not use the 1+?

Comment: @Rapptz: `rand()%51` will never return `51`. The expression you want is just `rand()%52`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your problem has to do with calling srand repeatedly and in quick succession.

Essentially, time(0) will return the same value if you call it fast enough, which means that the value that you seed rand with will be the same, which will return the same value for rand in your loop.  Try calling srand just once, before the for loop.  Eg:

```
srand(time(0));

for (int j = 0; j <= 51; j++)
{
    int i = 1 + rand()%52;
    int k = 1 + rand()%52;

    Card temp = theDeck[i];
    theDeck[i] = theDeck[k];
    theDeck[k]= temp;
}
```

Comment: Also, Benjamin Lindley's right that you should usually only call srand once instead of each time you get into the function.  The above is more of a kluge that should work and allow you to test whether it really is the problem.